# making two struct pointers equal

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So let's say i have a struct pointer called A and struct pointer called B:

```
struct example{
//variables and pointers
}*A
```

and then i have a pointer of datatype struct example:

```
struct example *B=malloc(sizeof(struct example));
```

If i do

```
A=B;
```

does this arithmetic operation mean that whatever struct pointer B is pointing to will be what struct pointer A is also pointing to? I get it with primitive datatype and pointers but struct confuse me because they have variables inside..

assume struct pointer A is set and everything

Comment: You have pointers here. So `A = B` make `A` point to the same place as `B`. If you had `struct example C; C = *B;`, that would copy the members of the struct `B` points to into the members of `C`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes with the following lines of code, A should point to the same location, B was pointing to.

```
/* Define the struct example datatype */
struct example{
    //variables and pointers
};

/* Declare A and B as pointers to struct example */
struct example *A;
struct example *B;

/* Allocate memory equivalent to the size of struct example
   and store the address in B */
B=malloc(sizeof(struct example));

/* Copy the address in B to A, so that A points to the same
   location B was pointing to */
A = B;
```

You should think of pointers as just another `unsigned long` variable which holds an address to a memory, (since the pointer just points to the address it holds).

Just as with any other variables, you can copy the address stored in one pointer variable to another.

Comment: A question. why do we have to dynamically allocate the memory to pointers in order to copy its data to other pointer?

Answer (score 1):

All you're doing is making A and B point to the same struct. For example, suppose your malloc() call reserved space for your struct at address 0x1000 (just an example).

Now, after your malloc(), B just holds the number 0x1000. So when you do A = B, you're just setting A to 0x1000 also. That way B->var1 is the exact same entity as A->var1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes... A and B are pointers, not values. When you say A = B, you are saying "set the pointer A to point to the same thing that B is pointing to" -- or, more specifically, both A and B will contain the same memory address after the assignment.

What you are really doing when you use A->someVar

{address of someVar} = {memory address of structure} + {offset of someVar in bytes relative to the start of the structure}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the following code:

```
struct example* A;
struct example* B;
B = malloc(sizeof(struct example));
A = B;
```

will lead to `A` pointing to the same memory as `B` does. However note, that changing the value of the pointer itself (`B`) will have no effect on the other pointer (`A`), so for example when you do:

```
free(B);
B = NULL;
```

the pointer `A` will still point to the memory, where the instance of `struct example` used to reside and thus `A` will become an invalid (*dangling*) pointer.

Answer (score 0):

a pointer saves an address of data in memory, the call of `malloc` return the the address of the first word where the memory areay you have allocated for your data starts.

You could imagine a pointer just like a piece of paper where you write down the number of a building, when you enter it you'll find apartments witch also have numbers and so on can it go.

So assigning the value of a pointer to an other pointer is just like taking another piece of paper an writing the number from the first paper on it.

Primitive data types and/or other pointers inside the `struct` are just like the apartments, they may show you some concrete stuff or let you enter some other area where you can find other stuff.